# Track SQL Server 2008 R2 DML changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not an Admin user. I would like to create a Trigger, that should capture invoked/affected tables,functions,views and SP names if there is any DML operations performed.

**For ex:** From UI, IF I insert a record my code will call SP and within that SP we have insert logic. Here I would like to get a name of invoked SP and Tables. 
Is that possible to create trigger without Admin access?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to track DML (insert/update/delete) and not DDL (create/alter) operations? How do you imagine "DML affected SP"?

Comment: @sepupic - Sorry I missed that point. I want to capture DML operations along with SP name.

Answer (score 0):

Table level ALTER –> Grants the ability to add or remove trigger objects.

All you need to have is to be granted ALTER rights on the table or database you are working on, no need to be an admin.

```
GRANT ALTER ON dbname.tablename TO [domain\userid];  
GO
```

You can see all the permissions that you may be granted here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql

Helpful links:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/83d22caf-cee1-44fb-b717-79f53d5f3b54/grant-create-trigger-privilege?forum=sqlsecurity

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/grant_revoke.php